# webkit2png not rendering correct font on some devices

Tags: css, fonts

I had a webpage with the css

```
font: normal normal 700 normal 14px / 24px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

This rendered the font in Segoe UI Bold on my desktop PC both in Chrome and in Firefox, as well as with `webkit2png`. On the raspberry pi however, the command `webkit2png temp.html -o out.png -x 700 1000` caused the font to be displayed in the same way as it would look without any css.

**How can I make `webkit2png` use the fonts I am telling it to use?**

Comment: I wrote this question with the intent of answering it myself, so that less other people will waste time with this. However, if anybody is able to not only answer with the fix but also _why_ it fixes it, I will accept that answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it turns out that replacing that CSS line with

```
font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
```

makes it work.
I believe that those code snippets *should be* equivalent though (apart from the fact that I'm only listing two fonts here)